# I want to select multiple rows but print a message next to a few of them with a specific value in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to print all the patients and what illness name they suffer from. If a patient suffers from 'Love sickness' it is supposed to print 'Critical condition' next to it. How do I do this without altering the table?

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT patientName, illnessName
FROM Patient
JOIN Suffers ON Suffers.patientID = Patient.patientID
```

I was thinking I could use `SELECT patientName, illnessName, 'Critical condition' AS condition` but I don't know how to do that for specifically those with 'Love sickness'

Some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to add a conditional piece of text to the illnessName. If that's the case the following should work:

```
SELECT p.patientName,
  s.illnessName + case when s.illnessName='Love sickenss' then ' Critical condition' else '' end as illnessName
FROM Patient p
JOIN Suffers s ON s.patientID = p.patientID
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `case when` to add 1 or multiple conditions.
- In the example below i have added love sickness and one random value i.e sickness 2. If you have only one then you can remove it, but if you have more than 1 you can just add more when statement.
- in the else statement you will have final condidion if you want. I passed a string value, but if you would want to ignore that then you can just doe else end

```
SELECT patientName, 
       illnessName,
       case when illnessName = 'Love sickness' then 'Critical Condition'
            when illnessName =  ' sickness 2' then  ' less critical'
            ........
            else 'No illness condition specified' end as condition_level
FROM Patient
JOIN Suffers ON Suffers.patientID = Patient.patientID
```